# serial port event handler not triggered in Windows 10

Tags: c#, serial-port

Following is my code which I used in the development.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM28");

        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;

        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        mySerialPort.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
        mySerialPort.Close();
    }

    private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                        object sender,
                        SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
        Console.Write(indata);
    }
```

But the problem is, this function is working fine in windows 7 pc. But not in Windows 10 pc. There isn't any error shown in windows 10.serial port opening, listening works fine. But in windows 10, it never triggers the method 'DataReceivedHandler'.

Comment: is the port name the same?

Comment: Yes.I have used the same port name. Is it different in windows 7 and windows 10?

Comment: COM28 is a very specific port name, what makes you think its the same on the other pc

Comment: Here I am using Vcom software configuration. In there, I have already set the port name to com48. Thats why I am using the same port name for both PCs.But I am not sure whether it is correct or not. But it works on windows 7 PCs. And also when I go to Windows 10, device driver, it shows there is a problem with this driver with the normal warning icon. Is it can be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this code works very well. I used to simulate the serial ports "Virtual Serial Port 9" and created the COM28 and COM30 interconnected.

To write in COM30 used the Termite 3.4 software, which submitted a "Hello World" for your software and it received.

Just I changed it in code, but no influence over its.

```
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM28")
        {
            BaudRate = 9600,
            Parity = Parity.None,
            StopBits = StopBits.One,
            DataBits = 8,
            Handshake = Handshake.None,
            RtsEnable = true
        };
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCvvo.png)